# TextField Disappears when editing Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

So I have a ViewController, inside it i have a TableView and at the bottom of it a View that contains a TextField and a Button.

When the keyboard appears I tried to put the View at the bottom just above the keyboard and my View appears only if I put my View in front like this :
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(SendMessageView)
(Just to be clear my View is visble and I can see it, it only dissapears when I try to move it on top of the keyboard when it appears)
So now that I can see my View when I mooved it above the keyboard, when I begin to type something my View dissapears instantly and I hane no clue why and I don't know how to fix this.
I hope I explained my problem clearly
Below this you'll find my entire code :

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class Chat_user: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var SendMessageView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var SendMessageInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var SendButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var MessageList: UITableView!

var cellMessage: CustomMessage!
var count = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let singleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.test))
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
    singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGestureRecognizer)
    SendMessageInput.delegate = self
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(SendMessageView)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(SendMessageInput)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(SendButton)
    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(MessageList)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func test(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        self.SendMessageView.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        self.MessageList.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: self.count - 1, section: 0)
        self.MessageList.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        self.SendMessageView.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        self.MessageList.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    self.count = 10
    return (self.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    self.cellMessage = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "message", for: indexPath) as? CustomMessage
    return (cellMessage)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return true
}
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Arkning

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue with frame-layout , you need to drag the bottom constraint of the `SendMessageView` and inside

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        self.SendMessageViewBottCon.constant += keyboardSize.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: self.count - 1, section: 0)
        self.MessageList.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) { 
      self.SendMessageViewBottCon.constant = 0 
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded() 
}
```

If you need animation insert

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: What is SendMessageViewBottCon.constant ?

Comment: `SendMessageViewBottCon` is an `@IBOutlet` of the bottom constraint of `SendMessageView`

Comment: So I need to link the bottom constraint from my storyboard to my class ?

Comment: @Arkning yes,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Also I tried your code but it doesn't work so do you have another solution ?